sending metric(celery tasks) to Azure Application Insight in chunks repeatedly (non stop)
from celery.signals import worker_process_init
from opentelemetry.instrumentation.celery import CeleryInstrumentor
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor



@worker_process_init.connect(weak=False)
def init_celery_tracing(*args, **kwargs):
    CeleryInstrumentor().instrument()
    configure_azure_monitor(
        connection_string=os.getenv("APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"),
        role_name=os.getenv("CONTAINER_APP_NAME", "unknown_service")
        
    )

django.setup()

Logs in console and in trace on Azure which not stop but in request tab its displays OK.
src-worker-1    | Response headers:
src-worker-1    |     'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
src-worker-1    |     'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
src-worker-1    |     'Server': 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
src-worker-1    |     'Strict-Transport-Security': 'REDACTED'
src-worker-1    |     'X-Content-Type-Options': 'REDACTED'
src-worker-1    |     'Date': 'Tue, 28 May 2024 19:09:45 GMT'
src-worker-1    | [2024-05-28 15:09:44,965: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-5] Transmission succeeded: Item received: 3. Items accepted: 3
src-worker-1    | [2024-05-28 15:09:45,033: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Request URL: 'https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com//v2.1/track'
src-worker-1    | Request method: 'POST'
src-worker-1    | Request headers:
src-worker-1    |     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
src-worker-1    |     'Content-Length': '3477'
src-worker-1    |     'Accept': 'application/json'
src-worker-1    |     'x-ms-client-request-id': 'd83836d0-1d25-11ef-99bb-0242ac130007'
src-worker-1    |     'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-azuremonitorclient/unknown Python/3.11.9 (Linux-5.15.146.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2-x86_64-with-glibc2.36)'
src-worker-1    | A body is sent with the request
src-worker-1    | [2024-05-28 15:09:45,048: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] Request URL: 'https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com//v2.1/track'
src-worker-1    | Request method: 'POST'
src-worker-1    | Request headers:
src-worker-1    |     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
src-worker-1    |     'Content-Length': '3478'
src-worker-1    |     'Accept': 'application/json'
src-worker-1    |     'x-ms-client-request-id': 'd83a9844-1d25-11ef-9ff9-0242ac130007'
src-worker-1    |     'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-azuremonitorclient/unknown Python/3.11.9 (Linux-5.15.146.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2-x86_64-with-glibc2.36)'
src-worker-1    | A body is sent with the request
src-worker-1    | [2024-05-28 15:09:45,058: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-6] Response status: 200
src-worker-1    | Response headers:
src-worker-1    |     'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
src-worker-1    |     'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
src-worker-1    |     'Server': 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
src-worker-1    |     'Strict-Transport-Security': 'REDACTED'
src-worker-1    |     'X-Content-Type-Options': 'REDACTED'
src-worker-1    |     'Date': 'Tue, 28 May 2024 19:09:46 GMT'
src-worker-1    | [2024-05-28 15:09:45,058: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-6] Transmission succeeded: Item received: 3. Items accepted: 3
src-worker-1    | [2024-05-28 15:09:45,154: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-9] Request URL: 'https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com//v2.1/track'
src-worker-1    | Request method: 'POST'
src-worker-1    | Request headers:
src-worker-1    |     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
src-worker-1    |     'Content-Length': '3477'
src-worker-1    |     'Accept': 'application/json'
src-worker-1    |     'x-ms-client-request-id': 'd84aa9dc-1d25-11ef-8b3d-0242ac130007'
src-worker-1    |     'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-azuremonitorclient/unknown Python/3.11.9 (Linux-5.15.146.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2-x86_64-with-glibc2.36)'
src-worker-1    | A body is sent with the request
src-worker-1    | [2024-05-28 15:09:45,158: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Response status: 200
src-worker-1    | Response headers:
src-worker-1    |     'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
src-worker-1    |     'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
src-worker-1    |     'Server': 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
src-worker-1    |     'Strict-Transport-Security': 'REDACTED'
src-worker-1    |     'X-Content-Type-Options': 'REDACTED'
src-worker-1    |     'Date': 'Tue, 28 May 2024 19:09:46 GMT'
src-worker-1    | [2024-05-28 15:09:45,159: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Transmission succeeded: Item received: 3. Items accepted: 3
src-worker-1    | [2024-05-28 15:09:45,195: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] Response status: 200
src-worker-1    | Response headers:
src-worker-1    |     'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
src-worker-1    |     'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
src-worker-1    |     'Server': 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
src-worker-1    |     'Strict-Transport-Security': 'REDACTED'
src-worker-1    |     'X-Content-Type-Options': 'REDACTED'
src-worker-1    |     'Date': 'Tue, 28 May 2024 19:09:45 GMT'
src-worker-1    | [2024-05-28 15:09:45,195: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] Transmission succeeded: Item received: 3. Items accepted: 3
src-worker-1    | [2024-05-28 15:09:45,275: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-9] Response status: 200
src-worker-1    | Response headers:
src-worker-1    |     'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
src-worker-1    |     'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
src-worker-1    |     'Server': 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
src-worker-1    |     'Strict-Transport-Security': 'REDACTED'
src-worker-1    |     'X-Content-Type-Options': 'REDACTED'
src-worker-1    |     'Date': 'Tue, 28 May 2024 19:09:45 GMT'
src-worker-1    | [2024-05-28 15:09:45,276: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-9] Transmission succeeded: Item received: 3. Items accepted: 3
src-worker-1    | [2024-05-28 15:09:45,305: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-10] Request URL: 'https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com//v2.1/track'
src-worker-1    | Request method: 'POST'
src-worker-1    | Request headers:
src-worker-1    |     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
src-worker-1    |     'Content-Length': '3477'
src-worker-1    |     'Accept': 'application/json'
src-worker-1    |     'x-ms-client-request-id': 'd861b2bc-1d25-11ef-bb99-0242ac130007'
src-worker-1    |     'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-azuremonitorclient/unknown Python/3.11.9 (Linux-5.15.146.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2-x86_64-with-glibc2.36)'
src-worker-1    | A body is sent with the request
I need to send it in one piece i guess not sure. So it block all other proccess.
